# ipython, from bash to variable

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, unix, jupyter-notebook

I have

> ```
> path='/path/2/foo'
>
> ls $path
> ```

yields a list of files in the path.  What do I do if I want to convert that to a list of strings of filenames?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir):

```
import os
path = '/path/2/foo'
filenames = os.listdir(path)
```